# Is "It was just one, isolated voice, venting frustration" a correct example of the comma usage?

Tags: commas, indefinite-article, semicolons

When I read the following piece quoted from The New York Times I wondered why the journalist doesn't use "an" before "isolated voice".

> As the Garden emptied Wednesday night, a fan near the upper press box shouted, “Phil Jackson!” to no one in particular. It was just one, isolated voice, venting frustration. But the sentiment could quickly become contagious.

I don't know why, but I suppose a best phrasing would be:

1. It was just one, **an** isolated voice, venting frustration.
2. It was just one isolated voice venting frustration.
3. It was just one venting frustration; an isolated voice.

Can anybody explain which is a better phrasing between "1" (with "an"), "2" (without the parenthetical commas), "3" (moving the phrase at the end, after the semicolon)? Or, is the journalist's phrasing better?

Answer (score 1):

The reporter's way of writing this is standard. He is expressing what he wants to say very particularly.

*One*, like any quantifier, serves as the determiner. *One **comma** isolated* indicates that *one* does not include *isolated* within its scope: this was not one isolated voice among many isolated voices but "just one voice" which was also an "isolated voice".

Moreover, the second comma tells us that it was not just one voice venting frustration among many voices venting frustration, it was one voice, which also happened to be venting frustration.

Comment: I don't agree the form is standard, or even correct.   “It” refers to *voice*, not to *fan* or to the general situation.  Of Carlo's examples, only #2, “It was just one isolated voice venting frustration” is usable, and might better be written “It was just one isolated voice, venting frustration”.

Comment: @jwpat Eh? I never suggested that *it* referred to *fan*. And I see nothing non-standard about the use of a comma to signify that *one* and *isolated* are coordinate adjectives.

Comment: @jwpat7 StoneyB's answer is supported by CGEL chapter 20, section 3.2.1, which offers basically the same interpretation ("the punctuation distinguishes coordination from the stacking of modifiers").

Comment: @jwpat7, StoneyB: I claim no special knowledge of whatever "standard" might mean in this context, but I find the comma after *"one"* to be an unwelcome distraction from the natural flow of the utterance - both in writing, and if I were to imagine it as representing a pause in speech. I'll also just say that I see no reason why any other words apart from [one isolated voice](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one+isolated+voice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) should be relevant to that comma, which doesn't occur in ***any*** of the 36 written instances of same in Google Books there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I don't much *like* it - I'd write it *just one voice, isolated, venting* myself - but I think it's legit. And I can certainly hear the reading--in Frank DeFord's voice, before he went senile.

Comment: @ StoneyB: oic. I upvoted jwpat's comment because I don't *like* the comma. To my layman's understanding *("standard" = most common, normal, unexceptional)* it's therefore ***not*** "standard" in that sense. But it is perfectly valid, grammatical, and could in principle be used to put a slightly difference nuance on the utterance. So technically speaking, it's "correct", even though I would definitely say it's a poor stylistic choice on the part of the hack.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sports columnists (not sportwriters, who are hardworking and often literate) inhabit a different literary universe from the rest of us.

Comment: @ StoneyB: To my mind, if the writer intended to emphasise both *one* and *isolated* as distinct elements, he'd do better with something like *"It was just one voice, an isolated voice, venting frustration."* Otherwise he's got an uphill struggle trying to defeat our natural tendency to understand *one isolated* as a single element that happens to use something akin to tautologous repetition for emphasis. But for me the bottom line is that all people who are *learning* English really need to know is that it's better without the comma, as would reflect normal speech in almost all cases.